# how to fill dynamic content of dynamic XFA form (itext 7)?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, adobe, xfa

I'm using itext 7 to fill dynamic xfa form. I tried example provided in itext website which work for static part of PDF but dynamic part so not displaying on render filled PDF.
The PDF have an add button, on clicking add button few fields appears. This fields are not displaying even when values for this fields are filled. Can anyone suggest any approach to solve this problem.

Comment: For such dynamics you usually need some software that not simply adds data to the form xml but which also executes the javascript code associated with such buttons. I'm not positively aware of any such software besides the known Adobe products.

Comment: The adobe product you referring to, is it adobe livecycle ? All I want is to fill the form programmatically. I'm willing to use any product which helps me fill this form programmatically. Thanks for comment @mkl

Comment: Xfa forms are a deprecated, obsoleted technology. As far as I know no one but Adobe fully supports it, and dynamic forms require a fairly complete support to fill. Thus, I doubt any new software of help for you will come out...

Comment: Hello! Did you found a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No, I didn't get any solution or workaround for this. My project scraped the whole module.